# Linphone EXE compilation issue in Windows-7

Tags: mingw, sip, msysgit, msys, linphone

I am new to linphone and trying to compile it on my windows machine.

My System configuration and installed softwares/dependencies for linphone are as below:

windows-7 32-bit OS platform

installed MinGW.exe 
installed MINGW32 (mingw32-git.exe)
installed inno compiler for build exe

I have downloaded linphone version 3.7 from website and followed all the steps from README.mingw file for compiling and making setup file of linphone, so far everything went fine without any errors.

But when i try to build setup.exe file from MINGW32 using command "make setup.exe", that time it throws below errors:

```
cp: cannot stst '/usr/.bin/libbzrtp-0.dll' : No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [other-cherrypick] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/sources/linphone'
make : *** [zip] Error 2
```

Please find attached screenshot of my compilation.

**Note: It gives same errors when i run "make zip"**

Do i miss anything? Is there any dependency problem? Please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look further down in the `README.mingw` file you will see the "building bzrtp" section. After building and installing bzrtp I was able to both `make setup.exe` and `make zip` in linphone.

Comment: Thanks for reply William Price & user4560691. Do you have compile linphone source completely and make exe setup file?